# Unable to import some packages from Anaconda with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, tweepy

I can not import tweepy/ or an other package on Visual Studio Code. I found some methods to fix that like:

https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/

I tried it but it doesn't work for me.

Here is the `python.path` that I set up in file `settings.json`, I installed pylint too.

```
python
"python.pythonPath":"C:\\Users\\thibichngoc.mac\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": false
```

Comment: what does the `pip install tweepy` / `pip3 install tweepy` output to you?

Comment: Two things. One, to expand on NutCracker's question, how did you install tweepy?

Two, that path you chose for "python.pythonPath" is the base interpreter and not what you should probably be pointing at. It's best to create a conda environment with a specified Python version and install into that (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments which are the official docs; the ones you found are at least 2 years out of date).